# Scipy tplquad syntax

Tags: python, math, scipy, numerical-integration

I wish to do the following integral in python using the tplquad function in scipy:

[image]

So far, I've used the syntax below:

```
def func(z, y, x):
        return (x**(b1 + x1 - 1))*(y**(b2 + x2 - 1))*(z**(b3 + x3 - 1))*((1-x-y-z)**(x4+b4-1))

t1 = tplquad(func, 1/2, 1, lambda y: 0, lambda y: 1-y, lambda y, z: 0, lambda y, z: 1 - y - z)
```

where **func** is the function we want to integrate: **f(p_1, p_2, p_3)**, z is p_3, y is p_2, x is p_1

Can anyone tell me what the correct syntax for using tplquad here should be?

**EDIT:** I'm having trouble with the limits - if the limits, if the limits of the inner most integral were 0 to p1, what would I use as the limits in terms of lambda functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use tplquad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431553/how-to-use-tplquad)

Comment: @ev-br I've seen the post, but the limits in that integral are constants, and I'm having trouble with the limits only, where my limits are functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution is correct. The analytical formula for the integral is (computed in Mathematica)

```
def ftest():
    a = b1 + x1 - 1
    b = b2 + x2 - 1
    c = b3 + x3 - 1
    d = b4 + x4 - 1
    return (gamma(1+a)*gamma(1+b)*gamma(1+d)*(-beta(1+c,3+a+b+d)*betainc(1+c,3+a+b+d,1/2)+(gamma(1+c)*gamma(3+a+b+d))/gamma(4+a+b+c+d)))/gamma(3+a+b+d)
```

It gives exactly the same result as `tplquad`. For example, if `b1=b2=b3=b4=2` and `x1=x2=x3=x4=2`, I get in both cases `1.7421194876552e-11`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but it's too long for a comment, and I thought it might be helpful.

You can do the integral analytically, in terms of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

I'll call the powers k (for b1 + x1 - 1), l, m, n.
The inner most integral is

```
x**k * y**l * Integral{ 0<=z<=1-x-y | z**m * ( 1-x-y-z)**n dz}
```

let r = 1-x-y. the substitution zeta = z/r transforms this to

```
   x**k * y**l * r**(m+1) * J
```

where

```
 J = Integral{ 0<=zeta<=1 | zeta**m * ( 1-zeta)**n dzeta}
   = Beta( m+1, n+1)
```

a similar procedure gets the integral over y too, and we are left with

```
K*Integral{ 0.5<=x<=1 | x ** k * (1-x)**(l+1) dx
```

where

```
K = Beta( m+1, n+1) * Beta( l+1, n+2)
```

The x integral can be espressed using the incomplete beta function as

```
B(k+1, l+2) - B(0.5; k+1, l+2)
```

Comment: `B(k+1, l+2) - B(0.5; k+1, l+2)` this term is negative somehow. Is it correctly written? `B(0.5; k+1, l+2)` is the incomplete beta function from 0 to 0.5 for the given range, right?

Comment: @ProgSnob yes, it is the incomplete beta function (not the regularised one). How the difference could be negative is a mystery, as the dirrefence is the integral of a non-negative function over (0,5, 1)